# SQL "Group" and "Count" categories

Tags: sql-server-2012

Edit.  This is a follow up from [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58056176/count-instances-of-multiple-invoices-and-pivot-on-location).  To simplify the question.  Assume a table

```
date  | id | type
01/01 |  1 |  F
02/01 |  1 |  F
02/01 |  1 |  F
03/01 |  1 |  S
03/01 |  1 |  S
04/01 |  1 |  F
04/01 |  1 |  S
05/01 |  1 |  S
```

I am looking for a way to summarise the above table by combination of transaction types per day.  If a person (id) has only one transaction per day it counts as a Single type.  If they have more than one it counts as a Multiple one.  I've done that with my original query and it works.  The output from the above table would be:

```
date  | Single | Multiple
01/01 |   1    |   0
02/01 |   0    |   1
03/01 |   0    |   1
04/01 |   0    |   1
05/01 |   1    |   0
```

I got that far and it works.  What's I'm struggling with (ie. don't have a clue of how to start) is how set up a query to show all possible combinations of Type (SS, FF, FS) instead of just counting the multiple transactions.  The desired output would be like:

```
date  | Single | # FF | # FS | # SS
01/01 |   1    |   0  |   0  |  0
02/01 |   0    |   1  |   0  |  0
03/01 |   0    |   0  |   0  |  1
04/01 |   0    |   0  |   1  |  0
05/01 |   1    |   0  |   0  |  0
```

Any constructive hints or ideas will be much appreciated.

Comment: please include sample data for all related tables. I see only sample data for `billing` table

Comment: @Squirrel - the question is about one table.  How to extract data from that one, single table.

Comment: your `original query` involves 3 tables `billing, billing_detail, locations`

Comment: also please ensure the sample data matches with the expected output. In the expected output i see dates like `2018/01/01` and `2018/01/04` which are not present in the sample data fiddle

Comment: @Squirrel - and yet the question begins with the words "Let’s assume the following simplified table".

Comment: so you mean i can ignore whatever was before that statement ? I think you have provided too much information to your problem and it confuses the reader

Comment: Thanks for the updates. This is much clearer now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is assuming that you have max 2 `types` per date.

You can use the `CASE WHEN` statement with `MIN()` and `MAX()` to check for combination of `FF`, `FS` or `SS`

```
select  [date],
    case when count(*) = 1 then 1 else 0 end as Single,
    case when count(*) >= 2 
         and  min([type]) = 'F'
         and  max([type]) = 'F'
         then 1
         else 0
         end as [# FF],
    case when count(*) >= 2 
         and  min([type]) = 'F'
         and  max([type]) = 'S'
         then 1
         else 0
         end as [# FS],
    case when count(*) >= 2 
         and  min([type]) = 'S'
         and  max([type]) = 'S'
         then 1
         else 0
         end as [# SS]
from    yourtable
group by [date]
```

EDIT :
for more then 3 types, just change the `count(*) = 2` to `count(*) >= 2` as long as the `type` are either `F` or `S`

Comment: Thanks.  That works well if I have only two transactions (which is really what I have specified in the original question).  What about a more general query where there can be multiple (3+) transactions such as FF(F)S, SS(S)F, FF(F) which could be grouped as FS, SF, FF?

Comment: Edited the answer.